# expand vector in condition-contingent way

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to do something that I thought would be simple but I am failing miserably. I want to expand a vector contingent on the values of another object (a separate data frame). Here's a reproducible example: I have the vector `v1`, which contains the values {1,2,3}. I would like to add the strings {"moon", "sun"} if the column `Species` in the `iris` dataframe contains the string "setosa". I have tried:

```
v1 <- c(1,2,3)
v1 <- c(v1, c("moon", "sun"))["setosa" %in% iris$Species]
[1] "1"    "2"    "3"    "moon" "sun"
```

This works, as you can see from the output above. But if the condition is not met, I get an empty vector, rather than the original `v1` (i.e. just {1,2,3}):

```
v1 <- c(v1, c("moon", "sun")) ["nonword" %in% iris$Species]
character(0)
```

I have also tried:

```
v1 <- ifelse("setosa" %in% iris$Species, c(v1, c("moon", "sun")), v1)
```

But this returns:

```
[1] "1"
```

Any suggestions on what I could do? I am sorry if the question is very basic, but I have been searching for answers in previous posts and I can't make anything work.

Thanks!

Comment: What is `foo` here

Comment: @akrun, sorry, foo = v1. I cleaned up the example for the post but forgot to make the replacement. I'll fix it in a sec.

Comment: @akrun, your solution also works (just tried it). I marked the other one because it is more concise: it only takes one line of code and it does not require building it function that i won't use elsewhere in the script (this is a one-time problem). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `if`/`else` instead of `ifelse` since `ifelse` returns vector of same length as `test` that is the reason why it returns output of length of 1 with `ifelse`.

```
if("setosa" %in% iris$Species) c(v1, c("moon", "sun")) else v1
#[1] "1"    "2"    "3"    "moon" "sun"

if("nonword" %in% iris$Species) c(v1, c("moon", "sun")) else v1
#[1] 1 2 3
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is relatd to the index.  here

```
"nonword" %in% iris$Species
#[1] FALSE
```

returns a single `FALSE` which will be recycled to the length of the vector we want to index, resulting in `character(0)`.  Instead, we may need to `rep`licate the logical vector to match the length of the output vector

```
v1 <- c(1,2,3)
v2 <- c("moon", "sun")
f1 <- function(vec1, vec2, expr) {         
    c(vec1, vec2)[rep(c(TRUE, expr), c(length(vec1), length(vec2)))]
}
f1(v1, v2, "nonword" %in% iris$Species)
#[1] "1" "2" "3"
f1(v1, v2, "setosa" %in% iris$Species)
#[1] "1"    "2"    "3"    "moon" "sun"
```